# Destroying / removing a Queue() in Redis Queue (rq) programmatically

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

Given:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

yesterday = Queue('yesterday', connection=Redis())
today = Queue('today', connection=Redis())
```

I would like to programmatically delete the Queue named 'yesterday'

Answer (score 4):

Try the following (you can validate all of this with redis-cli):

```
yesterday.empty()  # This will wipe out rq:queue:yesterday and all of its contents
del(yesterday)  # Deletes the variable itself
r = Redis()
r.srem('rq:queues', 'rq:queue:yesterday')  # Removed the entry from rq:queues set. The library unfortunately doesn't seem to clean this up by itself.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the rq library?

Comment: @CarlSagan, I poked around quickly in the rq library's public interface. I didn't find anything useful. You may want to just make a rq Queue wrapper that does all this cleanup inside `__del__`

Comment: The paramter `ttl` in `q.enqueue_call` could be used to clear queues of jobs. If it worked, that is.